# Socket.io not working on android react native

Tags: android, react-native, socket.io

I am trying to socket.io to react native. It works perfectly fine on iOS device but doesn't work on android. I was doing some research and found out you need to usesCleartextTraffic="true".

I did that and its still not working. Below is my code. Any help would be really appreciated.

server code

```
const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer)

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("hello",function (){
        io.emit("hello", "worldd");
    })
});

httpServer.listen(3000);
```

Client Side

```
useEffect(()=> {


    try {
      const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');


      socket.on("hello", (param) => {
        console.log(socket.id); // x8WIv7-mJelg7on_ALbx
        console.log(param);
      });


    } catch (e) {

      console.log(e)

    }


  });
```

Comment: What happens when it's not working? Is there an [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) (or https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what the issue was. I had put an actual url not use localhost ans it worked. I used ngrok for that

Comment: This was driving me absolutely nuts until I stumbled upon your comment and surprisingly this worked.... But why? Is there a reason Android can't connect to local host? Maybe it's because of a security concern the Android OS has put in place and using ngrok provides us with a secure connection over sockets?

Answer (score -1):

I think first you need to change the way you are setting up you server, change it to this instead as suggested by the documentation

```
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);
```

The calling socket emit and on seems to be correct so try this and let me know if it works.
you can also check full documentation here
https://socket.io/get-started/chat